# Where are the settings for the new search bar?

Tags: search, search-results

The new search bar that appeared today looks great but I'm not sure how to get the search results as it previously worked for lists and libraries. Is there a new setting? It appears to be looking for files in OneDrive if anything. Any help on where to find settings, why it is defaulting like this, and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: This is called 'Zero-query' search. It will show you recommendations powered by AI and the Microsoft Graph. These recommendations will get updated as you use the search. As you start typing your query, these suggestions will be refined, according to your query: documents, sites and people will be suggested to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not even sure how it appeared there because no-one else has that right now in my tenant.  And somehow my normal search bar has also disappeared. If you look at the left hand navigation bar, "Home" is at the top and the normal search bar is missing.

Comment: Hi, I think this is part of new release from Microsoft. They have proposed earlier to build a uniform search experience from all Microsoft products including SharePoint online. You can check if this new feature is deployed to your tenant from the Office 365 Admin center.

Comment: UBK - again thank you so much for responding. however, i do not have a functional search box anymore. any ideas on why the normal search bar over the home button would be missing and the top search bar would be showing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments above, this is part of a new feature rolled out by Microsoft in your tenant. Please check [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/roadmap?ms.url=roadmap&rtc=1&filters=&searchterms=34273) for details.

Basically, Microsoft is trying to provide uniform search experience on their Office 365 suite of products and this feature is now slowly rolling out to tenants. If you create a new Office 365 environment right now, this feature would be available.

[image]

This search bar, although is positioned differently, should work similar to before. Please remember, this is contextual search, i.e. the search will happen in the scope you are within. If you search from the home page, then it will search entire site, if you search from a document library, then it will search only that document library.

You will get similar experience if you go to [Office search](https://www.office.com/search?auth=2).